# android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/color_primary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

I have an include tag to another of my activity layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/tb">
</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/grade_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

And I have it implemented in my activity which extends AppCompatActivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tb);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run my app:

```
Error:(26, 29) error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Furthermore, when I view my layout in the editor, I receive the following message:

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or to fix the theme style references.
Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current layout.
```

And my styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

I don't see where I am going wrong. The correct theme is selected in the editor and my manifest file. All help is appreciated as always!

Comment: at the top of your activity there has to be `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` not `import android.widget.Toolbar;`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your XML, but in your java code you are importing `android.widget.Toolbar` which is a different type. Change your import to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and it should work.

Comment: @Steve nvm steve, i did the same xD

Comment: You're right. I switch from `import android.widget.Toolbar;` to `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`, and this fix my error. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

if your project is already migrated to AndroidX then import this
`import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`
 
else migrate to AndroidX by
 **Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX**
Full code Example of XML and Java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Events.Events_Main_Activity">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="8dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:title="Anime Title"
            app:titleEnabled="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/aa_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient" />
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_sec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="shshhs" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>



package com.uafappdevelopers.example;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
//note this import
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.uafappdevelopers.uafportal.R;
public class Events_Second_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
//add this for the navigation back button click event
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    finish();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_second);
    //change id to Your id
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_sec);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    setTitle("University of Agriculture Faisalabad");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;


toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Seems you have missed a line of code from you code block.

Answer (score 4):

this is working for the latest android versions:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarflwrs);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Notice, import **Toolbar** from:

`androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 1):

**FROM:**

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

**TO:**

androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Hi Golem and welcome to StackOverflow. This is basically the same answer by M.Noman Zaman (previous answer), please check carefully before posting an answer. Moreover, you should enclose your code in code blocks, you might want to have a look at [how to format text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Android import automatically "import android.widget.Toolbar;" but i imported "import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;" and then added " setSupportActionBar(toolbar);". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "<Toolbar" which is "<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" on "<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar".