# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

Hey Some one tell me why my android studio give this error?
I use support library v7 to handle backward compatibility.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, please post the stack trace where you are getting this exception, along with your code that is causing the exception. Please point out where lines in the stack trace refer to lines of code that you post.

Comment: Provide your code sample where you are using tollbar. Also post your logcat.

Comment: your title itself contains your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You did not import the right package to handle backward compatibility.
Try this package to import in your code to handle backward compatibility.

**import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;**

Answer (score 1):

You use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in your XML, but in your java code you are importing android.widget.Toolbar which is a different type. Change your import to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and it should work.

Visit: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798853/3235048)

Answer (score 0):

You have used android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and casting it to android.widget.Toolbar. Check your imports.