# Android Get Toolbar Issue

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I am trying to learn android coding and came to an unusual situation with toolbar.
Everytime i try to obtain my toolbar into the code with findViewById(R.id.toolbar),
my app keeps crashing for unclear reason.

I have been looking in to this topic:
[android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798801/android-widget-toolbar-cannot-be-converted-to-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar)

I think i did exactly what they wrote in there but i am still helpless to find my problem.
To be more clear i made a short video of my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9H0Zi1lI84

Java:

```
package com.example.toolbartest;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope someone can guide me thru this as i am a newbie with Android Studio.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to use the fully-qualified class name in the layout tag; i.e., `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar ...`.

Comment: Ohh yess that was the issue thank you very much !!!